# Batch Script for Ping Monitoring with background change and alarm

Tags: batch-file

Actually I have a code for Ping Monitoring and Alarm. It's working but, when there is no Ping to a specific IP it shows only a blank screen with background change. I want to show the exact error which is displayed in the cmd. like "Destination host unreachable" or "TTL Expired in transit". there is any way to do that??? My code is

```
echo off & cls
:top
PING -n 1 8.8.8.8 -l 1 | FINDSTR /C:"TTL=" /C:"Destination host unreachable" /C:"Request timed out." /C:"TTL Expired in transit"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET OUT=4F & start \music.mp3) Else (SET OUT=2F)
color %OUT%
ping -n 2 -l 127.0.0.1 >nul
GoTo top
```

Comment: Remove `Echo Off`

Comment: @CatCat, how is that going to show the output when it is all being filtered by the `FIND` command to only show lines that contain `TTL`?

Comment: The `FIND` command is filtering the `PING` output to only show lines that contain `TTL`.  If you still want to filter specific lines but need to show multiple lines then switch to using the `FINDSTR` command.  `FINDSTR /C:"TTL=" /C:"Destination host unreachable"`

Comment: @Squashman I modify the code with your suggestion but now the errors are showing exactly. but the background color doesnot change. it remain constant on correct ping and error case.

Comment: @NithinHaridas, you need to have a space between the right parentheses and the `ELSE`.

Comment: @Squashman yaa.. but no change in the result. actually i give green color to normal ping and red color to packet loss. but my output is in normal ping background is green. in packet loss case 1st packet loss is shown in red background and from next packet loss message the background color changes to green.

Comment: @NithinHaridas, if the `FINDSTR` command is true, the errorlevel is set to zero.  I assume you are expecting to use the errorlevel from the `PING` command.